# C++ struct implement derived interface

Tags: c++, struct, visitor-pattern

Upon experimenting with the Visitor Pattern in C++, I have come to a silly problem with regards to implementing a derived interface. I suspect that I do not know how to formulate the question correctly, as I have not found a solution to this elsewhere.

I have the following base struct:

```
struct Visitor {
    virtual void visit(const Resources) = 0;
    virtual void visit(const Population) = 0;
};
```

I wish to declare a couple of concrete implementations of Visitor along with some extra functionality. **This is how I want my declarations to look like**:

```
struct EndVisitor : public Visitor{
    virtual bool hasEnded();
};

struct SetupVisitor : public Visitor{
};

struct ScoreVisitor : public Visitor{
    virtual unsigned int getScore();
};
```

When defining, say for instance ScoreVisitor, the IDE and compiler recognizes the extra function declarations in ScoreVisitor:

```
unsigned int ScoreVisitor::getScore() {
    return total;
}
```

However, implementing the Visitor functions are not recognized by the compiler or IDE (`Funtion 'visit' not declared in class 'ScoreVisitor'`):

```
void ScoreVisitor::visit(const Resources resources) {
    total += resources.score;
}

void ScoreVisitor::visit(const Population population) {
    total += population.score;
}
```

If I declare ScoreVisitor repeating the Visitor functions, the code compiles, however this leaves me with a lot of copy-pasted code in all specialized declarations of Visitor, which I wish to avoid. **This is not how I want my declarations to look like**:

```
struct ScoreVisitor : public Visitor{
    virtual void visit(const Resources);
    virtual void visit(const Population);
    virtual unsigned int getScore();
};
```

How do I declare specialized versions of Visitor without having to copy-paste all the functionality that Visitor already declares?

Comment: Welcome to C++! You need to declare all the members of any class correctly before defining them. Even virtual methods which you are overriding from base classes.

Comment: Thanks Nim! I understand your reply as: I will not be able to avoid declaring the interface functions in a specialized declaration of Visitor?

Comment: Yes, unless you have a hierarchy where some functionality is implemented at varying levels of abstraction..

Comment: Ok, this answers my question. Will you create an answer to this question with the information from your comments? The important detail is that what I am trying is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to avoid having to declare methods you are overriding from a base class in a derived class. This is the way the language is. Typically people group functionality into some form of inheritance hierarchy to expose common functionality.

NOTE a couple of syntax related matters, `virtual` is optional for derived classes (a function with a similar signature is virtual by default), since C++11, some folks have taken to using `override` (I fall into this category too) as it will catch - at compile time - any cases where in a derived class a method is expected to be virtual, but in a base class it is not declared as such.

I'm sure the above is an example, but it's critical you don't forget a virtual destructor in the base class!

Answer (score 2):

Its not ideal but you could do it with a subclass which inherits from Visitor and have the other classes derive from that:

```
struct Visitor {
    virtual void visit(const int) = 0;
};

struct VisitorImplementor : public Visitor
{
    virtual void visit(const int) override { /* implement */}
};


struct EndVisitor : public VisitorImplementor {
    virtual bool hasEnded() { return true; }
};
```

Now you can create instances of EndVisitor and call visit on it

```
EndVisitor v;

v.visit(10);
```

Comment: Thanks Servé! I see how implementing the functions can do the trick with regards to making them visible in derived classes. However, this moves in the opposite direction of the question: I wish to be as lazy as possible, hence I would like to keep out implementations of the derived classes except for the very last ones.